# Why are my Callback functions not working?

Tags: python, callback, mqtt, paho

Here is my code. No matter what I try I can't get the callback functions to work. Nothing happens when client connects or when a message is received. I've tried all the different loop options. All I can find are things I've already tried. I've tried everything I've found online and its still not working. The Callback functions just won't do anything.

````
import json
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt


# Callback function when the client connects to the MQTT broker
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))
    # Subscribe to a topic when connected (optional)
    client.subscribe("test/topic")

# Callback function when a message is received from the MQTT broker
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("test")
    print("Received message: " + msg.payload.decode())
    client.disconnect()

# Create an MQTT client instance
client = mqtt.Client()

# Set the callback functions
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

# Connect to the MQTT broker (replace broker_address with your broker's IP/hostname)
client.connect("broker_adress", 1234, 60)
print("connected")

# Start the MQTT network loop to process incoming and outgoing messages
client.loop()
print("loop started")

client.subscribe("topic")
print("subscribed")
time.sleep(1)


# Publish a message to a topic (replace test/topic with your desired topic)
client.publish("topic", "Hello, MQTT!")
print("published")
# Wait for a few seconds to receive any messages (you can use time.sleep() for testing purposes)
# For a more robust implementation, you can use client.loop_forever() instead of time.sleep
time.sleep(2)

# Disconnect from the MQTT broker
client.loop_stop()```
````

Answer (score 1):

As per [the docs](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python#loop) when using `client.loop()` you must:

> Call regularly to process network events.

The example given is:

```
run = True
while run:
    mqttc.loop()
```

So `client.loop()` is designed for use in a situation where you already have a loop (for instance checking a sensor reading), and call `client.loop()` on each iteration (meaning it's called regularly).

I think you intended to use `client.loop_start()` (based on the call to `client.loop_stop()` at the end of the code). Making that change (replace `client.loop()` with `client.loop_start()`) is likely to resolve your issue.

An alternative would be to move the `client.subscribe("topic")` and `client.publish("topic", "Hello, MQTT!")` into `on_connect` (the recommended spot for `subscribe` calls) and use `client.loop_forever()`

Answer (score -1):

1. Check MQTT broker address: Double-check the "broker_address" you are using in the `client.connect()` call. Ensure it is the correct IP/hostname and port of your MQTT broker.
2. Use client.loop_start(): Instead of `client.loop()`, use `client.loop_start()`. This will start a separate thread for the MQTT network loop, which can help to process incoming and outgoing messages.
3. Check if the connection is being established: After calling `client.connect()`, add a short delay to allow the connection to be established before moving forward. You can use `time.sleep(1)` to wait for a second.
4. Use client.loop_forever(): Instead of manually stopping the loop after a few seconds, consider using `client.loop_forever()`. This will keep the client connected indefinitely and handle incoming messages continuously.
   ....
   Now do try to this code...

```
import json
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# Callback function when the client connects to the MQTT broker
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))
    # Subscribe to a topic when connected (optional)
    client.subscribe("test/topic")

# Callback function when a message is received from the MQTT broker
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("test")
    print("Received message: " + msg.payload.decode())
    client.disconnect()

# Create an MQTT client instance
client = mqtt.Client()

# Set the callback functions
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

# Connect to the MQTT broker (replace broker_address with your broker's IP/hostname)
client.connect("broker_adress", 1234, 60)
print("connected")

# Start the MQTT network loop to process incoming and outgoing messages
client.loop_start()
print("loop started")

client.subscribe("topic")
print("subscribed")
time.sleep(1)

# Publish a message to a topic (replace test/topic with your desired topic)
client.publish("topic", "Hello, MQTT!")
print("published")

# Keep the client running and handling incoming messages indefinitely
client.loop_forever()
```

Try running this updated code and see if the callback functions are triggered when you connect and receive messages. If there still any issue, please ensure that your MQTT broker is set up correctly and reachable from your device.
Also, check for any potential firewall or security configurations that might block the connection.

Comment: Your example is calling `client.loop_start()` and then `client.loop_forever()`; this will result in two message loops running concurrently which may have unpredictable results (`loop_start` just calls `loop_forever()` in another thread). Calling `client._thread.join()` would probably work (not really suggesting this as the `_` indicates this is intended to be private). Of course if OP really just wants to send one message then disconnect, [`single.Publish`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/tree/master#single) would be a better option.